# Why is my PySerial write() function returning unexpected data?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am building a GUI interface using python to send serial data to an Arduino using pySreial. Stared facing issues with the data being sent to i tried a basic srial write program to figure out the problem.
The following code on being executed outputs b'' .

```
import serial

import time

serialcomm = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

serialcomm.timeout = 1

while True:
    serialcomm.write(b'Hello, Serial!')

    time.sleep(0.5)

    print(serialcomm.readline())

serialcomm.close()
```

I would really appritiate it if someone could help me figure out why this ouucrs.
Thank You.

Comment: Seems that the issue lies with how you are reading the serial data. The serial.readline() function reads until it encounters a newline character (\n), but in your Arduino code, it doesn't seem like you are sending a newline character after writing the data.

Comment: Facing the same issue even when I replace the .readline() with read().

Comment: What is running on the Arduino? What sort of data is it sending to your Python code? Have you verified (e.g., using a serial communication program) that the Arduino is behaving as expected?